# Append Int to Data in Swift 3

Tags: swift, datagram

I am writing datagram for sending it to a server via UDP socket. How can I append Int to the end of a datagram (already composed `Data`)?

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? You'll get more and better answers If you show what you've tried, and demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself. See [Ask]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the

```
public mutating func append<SourceType>(_ buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer<SourceType>)
```

method of `Data`. You probably also want to convert the value
to  network (big-endian) byte order when communicating between
different platforms, and use fixed-size types like `(U)Int16`,
`(U)Int32`, or `(U)Int64`.

Example:

```
var data = Data()

let value: Int32 = 0x12345678
var beValue = value.bigEndian
data.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &beValue, count: 1))

print(data as NSData) // <12345678>
```

---

**Update for Swift 4/5:**

```
let value: Int32 = 0x12345678
withUnsafeBytes(of: value.bigEndian) { data.append(contentsOf: $0) }
```

The intermediate *variable* is no longer needed.

Comment: This gives me `Initialization of 'UnsafeBufferPointer<Int32>' results in a dangling buffer pointer`

Comment: @h345k34cr: Thanks for letting me know. I have added an updated version which should compile without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do it:

```swift
var data = Data()
     
let value: Int32 = 0x12345678
var bigEndianVal = value.bigEndian

withUnsafePointer(to: &bigEndianVal) {
    data.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: 1))
}
```